# Is this basic function space compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $A=L^2(X)$ be the space of square integrable functions on a compact Euclidean space $X$. If we equip $A$ with the usual 2-norm, is $A$ compact?

Edit:
And if we restrict AA by adding the assumption that the functions are totally bounded, i.e. the supremum norms of all the functions are bounded by a constant?

Comment: No, for two different reasons: 1) it's a vector space 2) it's not even locally compact.

Comment: And if we restrict $A$ by adding the assumption that the functions are totally bounded, i.e. the supremum norm of all the functions are bounded by a constant?

Comment: Look at my answer. All the functions have sup norm 1.

Comment: I remember something along the lines "A subset is compact iff it is closed and almost finite dimensional.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $X=[0,1]$, then the sequence $\{e^{2\pi inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: By the way, this shows that even the closed unit ball isn't compact

Comment: Do you see what assumption I need to add to make A compact?

Comment: You could try the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, though that's for continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

$d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ is an unbounded metric. Any metric on a compact space is bounded.